# How to make custom style folding comment in vs.code

Tags: visual-studio-code, styles, comments

I work in typescript, using the "vs code" editor.

I want to group similar functions in `// #region myFunctions`  commentary scope.
It's an good future, but, when I collapse this, it's the risk of deleting it accidentally.

How to custom styling for this approach.
how to achieve this?

Comment: how bad could it really be if you delete it accidentally? Do you not review your changes before staging them to version control? :/

Comment: I have so habit, to remove unnecessary comments. Maybe I do it before pushing them to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following solution. I've installed vs code extension "better comments".  Then I made the comment `// * Mycomment`, at the header of the code, which I wanted to make collapsable. Then I select appropriate part of the code and from 'Command Pallete...', choose menu - "Create Manual Folding Range from Selection". That's all.
The range header has a custom style, different from the usual comment, and if even I accidentally will delete this line, it doesn't affect the collapsed code range.